# doesn't exist in current condition in c# better way writing this?

Tags: c#

I have 3 picture box, all allow nullable value. what I am trying to do is instead write all possible if conditions; I try to assign variables, but my variables are out of scope. any better solution, please

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

if (imGuest != null) 
{
     imGuest.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png);  
     byte[] arr = ms.ToArray(); 
} 
else 
{ 
     int? arr = null ; 
}

if (imDoc != null) 
{ 
     imDoc.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png); 
     byte[] arrDoc1 = ms.ToArray(); 
} 
else 
{ 
     int? arrDoc1 = null; 
}

if (imDoc2 != null) 
{ 
     imDoc2.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png); 
     byte[] arrDoc2 = ms.ToArray();
}
else 
{ 
     int? arrDoc2 = null; 
}


using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_insert", MainClass.con))
{
    // code here
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@img", arr);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@doc1", arrDoc1);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@doc2", arrDoc2);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

```cs
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    Func<Image, byte[]> getImage = (Image img) =>
    {
        if (img == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        img.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png);
        return ms.ToArray();
    };

    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_insert", MainClass.con))
    {
        // code here
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@img", getImage(imGuest));
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@doc1", getImage(imDoc));
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@doc2", getImage(imDoc));
    }
}
```